# .htaccess RewriteRule creates 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following .htaccess which creates Error 500:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^mysite/view/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /mysite/view.php?id=$1&l=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This site /localhost/mysite/view.php?id=2987732&l=de
creates normaly a fine page.
But /localhost/mysite/view/2987732/de should work with this .htaccess. But no function!!

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually _read_ what the error is instead of having to _guess_ or ask here.

Comment: The rule looks fine, it might be that the rewrite module is not available in the http server.

Comment: I use XAMPP on Ubuntu.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine. And does not really help to find out what the issue is :-)

Comment: [Wed Jun 22 20:52:48.087502 2016] [core:alert] [pid 32579] [client 127.0.0.1:32872] /opt/lampp/htdocs/streamdream/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: I have testet: [L, QSA, NC] instead. No function again!

Comment: In your last comment there are spaces before the flags, which will cause this error.